# Java thread execution order after unlock

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, monitor

Let's say I have 2 threads, *t1* and *t2*, and a lock object, *m*. Thread *t1* is in an infinite loop, where at each iteration, it grabs a lock on *m*, does some work, unlocks *m* and starts over immediately. During one iteration, *t2* requests a lock on *m* but gets blocked by *t1* and has to wait. Now, when *t1* unlocks *m*, is it guaranteed that *t2* will obtain the next lock on *m*? or can *t1* sneak ahead of it at the next iteration?

Generally, is there a queue set up for waiting threads? If *t1* has the lock, and all remaining threads also wanting that lock get blocked in the following order: *t2*, *t3*, ..., will the remaining threads continue execution in the order that they were blocked (e.g. *t2* runs, then *t3*, etc.)?

(I briefly perused the java spec and couldn't find the answer. If it's in there, please let me know, and I will go back to read more carefully.)

Thanks! (First SO post, woohoo!)

Comment: Ok, so "fairness" was the concept I was looking for. To recap (correct me if I'm wrong): `synchronized` statements are not fair, where "fair" is defined via (from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10264/)): "A fair lock is one where the threads acquire the lock in the same order they asked for it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a queue and it can be fair or not. Fair queues are more expensive and non-fair are faster (who wins the CAS wins the lock).
check [java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html) for further info.

> will the remaining threads continue
>   execution in the order that they were
>   blocked (e.g. t2 runs, then t3, etc.)?

The main issue is that they are executed concurrently/simultaneously, you can't truly define order for 2 events that are executed in the same time. But w/ fair (unrecommended due to extra costs) locks any thread that manages to enlist itself for the lock will get eventually get to own it.

Comment: so the race to get blocked has nothing to do with the subsequent race to obtain the freed lock?

Comment: @heycosmo, The code that unparks (after unlock) is in `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.unparkSuccessor`; while the threads are kept in a queue, the unparker thread is not exactly guaranteed to obtain the lock. *Thread to unpark is held in successor, which is normally just the next node.  But if cancelled or apparently null,  traverse backwards from tail to find the actual non-cancelled successor.* Open the class and read the description how it works, there is a walkthrough the signals beginning w/ *Wait queue node class.*

Comment: unless clear: even if the thread is unparked it has to compete for the lock w/ the rest of the threads attempting to acquire it (even if some blocked threads experiences sporadic unpark, it can participate), there is a brief moment when the lock is free to be taken and the next successor thread unparked.

Comment: @bestsss: ok, thanks, but my comment-question was more for clarification on the standard java locks implementation. Sorry, that was not clear.

Comment: @heycosmo, you mean the one using `synchronized` keyword? They do use (at least in hotspot) similar strategy but there is more, incl. biased locking which makes `synchronized(xxx)` very cheap (few cpu clocks, just load/compare) when the lock is uncontended. Java native locks (hotspot/azul, suppose the rest of the JVM vendors too) are not implemented w/ native code but use similar algorithm in C.

Comment: @heycosmo, I guess I am mislead by `unlock` and `freed lock`, java ones are called `monitors` and their commands are monitorEnter/monitorExit (basically what happens w/ synchronized)

Comment: Just finished a nice read [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10264/) which has answered my high-level questions. I'm still curious about the underlying implementation (e.g. if there is a queue of waiting threads, which is ordered, how does a random thread of the bunch get selected to acquire the next lock?), but maybe that's for another time. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @heycosmo this is the code for ObjectMonitor in hotspot, it uses spinlock and linked queue for what you ask (i.e. the built-in locks in java) http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid70893DD2B1CB31B77535B557A5F40737DEFFDF1C.aspx?s=zombie

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no such guarantees. You can advise Java to be [ReentrantLock objects to be fair](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock(boolean)), but that's advisory and does not guarantee any order.

In general, you cannot (without explicit synchronization to achieve it) guarantee such an order, because *t2* could have been interrupted before it even acquired the thread, and it's solely up to the OS to decide which thread gets resumed when.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no guarantee for most purposes. You'll notice some of the java.util.concurrent abstractions offer the option of a "fair lock" - which does more or less guarantee each thread waiting on a lock will eventually be called (not a specific order). Without fairness, there is no guarantee. OTOH, fairness is EXTREMELY expensive. (See Java Concurrency In Practice for some benchmarks), and usually, probablistic likelihood is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can guarantee order by using fair [Semaphore](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). Standard built-in Java locks/monitors aren't fair a do not queue orders in a fair manner.

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1, true);

//usage:
sem.acquire();
try {
  //holding a lock
  //of course both threads share the same semaphore
} finally {
  sem.release();
}
```

With locks theoretically T1 can take a lock in next iteration again after releasing it, despite the fact that T2 already waits for it. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: the code for ReentrantLock and Semaphor is practically the same when created w/ fair option. You can look at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.FairSync and java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.FairSync